# Create a table in server side asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I have this code, that create a table in a table.
In the last col of the outer table there is a link that when click on it it open the inner table.

The code:

Html:

```
<div id="shutfuyotTable" runat="server">
<table class="tblShutaf" dir="rtl" runat="server">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>num</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>sum1</td>
            <td>sum2</td>
            <td>notes</td>
            <td>moreData</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row1</td>
            <td>row1</td>
            <td>row1</td>
            <td>row1</td>
            <td>row1</td>
            <td><a href='#' id="row1" class='js-showmore'>row1</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="moredata">
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="Table1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2</td>
            <td>row2</td>
            <td>row2</td>
            <td>row2</td>
            <td>row2</td>
            <td><a href='#' id="row2" class='js-showmore'>row2</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="moredata">
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="Table2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3</td>
            <td>row3</td>
            <td>row3</td>
            <td>row3</td>
            <td>row3</td>
            <td><a href='#' id="row3" class='js-showmore'>row3</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="moredata">
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="Table3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
$(".js-showmore").on("click", function() {        
    $(this).closest("tr").next(".moredata").toggle();
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.moredata {
display: none;
}
```

I want to do the same thing, but I want to create the table from the server side (vb)
I will get the data from a mainframe computer and don't know how many rows will be in the out table.
In the inner table will be 5 rows.

I know I need to do it in the Page_Load, but don't know where to start.
(Maybe do a tmpstr stringBuilder and do concatenation to the id of the div?!?)

I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question and not just a link. Also, what have you tried in VB so far?

Comment: Read about the Repeater control in Asp.Net. It could come in handy.

Comment: @Yatrix
I don't know where to start so I didn't write in the vb yet.
I'm a newbie in vb and need some help of getting started.

Comment: Have you read about Repeater or a gridview?

Comment: @shlomi You should probably get a tutorial/book and learn VB. That's the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim table As new HtmlTable
table .Attributes.Add("class","test")

Dim row As HtmlTableRow
Dim cell As HtmlTableCell
For i As Integer = 0 To rowNumber
row = new HtmlTableRow

cell = new HtmlTableCell
cell.InnerHtml = "data"

row.Cells.Add(cell)

yourtable.Rows.Add(row)

Next
yourPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(table)
```